# converting string address to IP address for sockets call

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, gethostbyname

The following client code is attempting to prepare to send a UDP datagram.
However, the address is not set properly, so the send goes nowhere.

The error I am getting is:
sendto: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character

I assume this is talking about the address, not the data being sent.

Can anyone identify the problem?

```
int sendSock; // socket for listening to other side (same for client and server)
struct sockaddr_in addr;
struct addrinfo* res = nullptr;

int initClient(const char hostname[], const char port[]) throw (Exception) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=0;
    hints.ai_flags=AI_ADDRCONFIG;
    int err = getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &res);
    if (err != 0) {
      throw Exception(__LINE__, "failed to resolve remote socket address");
    }
    sendSock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sendSock < 0) { 
    throw Exception(__LINE__, strerror(errno));
    }

    struct hostent* hp = gethostbyname(hostname); // look up host name
    if (hp == nullptr) {
        throw Exception(__LINE__, "Can't find host");
    }

}
```

the call is:

```
    sendto(sendSock,buf,end, 0,res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen)
```

Here is the addrinfo object in the debugger:

```
p *res
$5 = {ai_flags = 0, ai_family = 23, ai_socktype = 2, ai_protocol = 0, ai_addrlen = 28, ai_canonname = 0x0,
  ai_addr = 0x60003a660, ai_next = 0x60003a690}
 p *res->ai_addr
$6 = {sa_family = 23, sa_data = "\023\210", '\000' <repeats 11 times>}
```

It does not look to me like the correct address is there, but none of the calls along the way are failing.

Comment: The `af_family` should be `AF_INET`.

Comment: tried replacing:  hints.ai_family=AF_INET; //AF_UNSPEC; 
no change

Comment: Are you using IPv4, IPv6? If you are compiling under Windows: is unicode support set? What is port value?